# Scriptlet Inside EL Expression

Tags: jsp, el, scriptlet

I have an EL expression in my JSP and **inside that EL** there needs to be a Scriptlet.

The below syntax is not working. Thanks

```
<c:if test="${<%=budgetActionForm%>.readOnly == false}">
```

Error

```
 javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${<%=budgetActionForm%>.readOnly == true
```

Comment: You can't use scriptlets inside EL. Period. You should not use scriptlets AT ALL. budgetActionForm should be a page- or request- or session- or application-scoped attribute.

Comment: Trust me, if I had a choice I wouldn't be using scriptlets.

Comment: The EL can only access attributes. Not local variables. So, if this is the only way, do `<% pageContext.setAttribute("budgetActionForm", budgetActionForm); %> <c:if test="${!budgetActionForm.readOnly}">`